# Is there a missing ground wire in my pedestal service circuit?

Tags: electrical-panel, inspection, meter

I just had a electrical inspection stated 2 hot 1 neutral and one ground needed.

I thought all of that was there.

[image: meter box n breakerbox]

Here are the inspection forms. I have no clue what is wrong or what is correct.

[image]

Comment: That's a PVC conduit exiting out the bottom, correct? Also, what size is that grounding electrode conductor (single bare wire) that exits out the bottom of the meter-main, and is that PVC conduit run continuous to the house, or does it terminate somewhere underground?

Comment: Please consider [merging your unregistered and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and most importantly [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 4):

You are being written up for a missing **Equipment Grounding Conductor (EGC)** which is the ground wire that goes with hots and neutrals in every circuit or feeder.

The thing between this meter-main and your house is **feeder** not service wire.  Above the meter is **service** wire.   Feeder requires EGC, service does not.

### What I see

is 200A service coming from the top.

I see a bare wire that is part of the **Grounding Electrode System** which bonds the meter-main chassis itself to local grounding rods.   However this is not an EGC ("ground wire") and does not go anywhere an EGC needs to go.

I see the main feeder going into the lower pipe **in 3 wires**.  I see **no ground wire (EGC)**, so yeah, the inspector got it right.

Fire your electrician.  *What were they thinking?*

If the power company installed this feeder, that would be why. They follow a different codebook (NESC) and they're not used to working in NEC rules.  *They make this mistake all the time*.

Some people think that if the pole has a ground rod (GES) and the house has a ground rod (GES), they don't need a ground wire (EGC) also, *because there's dirt between the two*.  Um... dirt doesn't conduct electricity that well :)

### What to do

You will need to add an appropriate sized ground wire to the pipe.  If the hot wires are *exactly* #2/0 Copper or #4/0 Aluminum, you can use a #6 Cu or #4 Al ground wire.  (However, if the hot wires are larger than that, *the ground must also be larger, forcing you to #4 Cu or #2 Al)*.

The added wire can't exceed conduit fill limits.  The ground wire can be bare **if it's copper**, which helps with conduit fill.  It's OK to use aluminum hots + copper ground.

You can fish *just the wire* if you can successfully get a fishing tape down that conduit with the wires in there.  If not, you'll have to pull the 3 wires and then pull them back in with the 4th wire.

Comment: "in 3 wires" is bolded, so that's important, but why? Should the main feed be a cable, not individual wires? There is a ground, but it appears to exit the box via its own hole and, presumably, goes to the ground. I presume there should also be a ground going down the conduit to whatever this is feeding?

Comment: @FreeMan didn't see your comment because I was doing a major edit that may address your issue.

Comment: "cable" isn't necessary, but it needs to be "4 wires" because the ground from meter-main to panel is missing. Got it. Thanks!